# Angular Ionic data binding issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am new to Angular, and trying to build an app in ionic. I have 2 fields on screen, and I want to implement the following.

1. when user enters something in the `price` field, I want to update `weight` field accordingly.
2. when user enters something in the `weight` field, I want to update the `price` field.

Here is my code.

```
    <div class="col col-50">
        <div class="card">
            <label class="item item-input">
                <input ng-model="sale_item_weight" value="{{ sale_item_weight }}" ng-change="syncWithItemPrice()" type="number" placeholder="Enter Weight">
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-50">
        <div class="card">
            <label class="item item-input">
                <input ng-model="sale_item_price" value="{{ sale_item_price }}" ng-change="syncWithItemWeight()" type="number" placeholder="Enter Price">
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and in my controller I have these methods:

```
$scope.syncWithItemWeight = function() {
   var itemPrice = $scope.sale_item_price;
   $scope.sale_item_weight = parseInt(itemPrice) * 2;

}

$scope.syncWithItemPrice = function() {
   var itemWeight = $scope.sale_item_weight;
   $scope.sale_item_price = parseInt(itemWeight) / 2;

}
```

When I change one field the other one doesn't get updated. The functions are getting called, I have made sure of that by adding an `alert` to them.

Comment: Its seems to be working fine for me, can you post your whole code. Its most probably a typo. See this [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/1WUamNKfg8IfRufwNs5r?p=info)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a json object instead of using directly scope variable.

Use this below code.

HTML

```
<div class="col col-50">
    <div class="card">
        <label class="item item-input">
            <input ng-model="sale_item.sale_item_weight" value="{{ sale_item.sale_item_weight }}" ng-change="syncWithItemPrice()" type="number" placeholder="Enter Weight">
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col col-50">
    <div class="card">
        <label class="item item-input">
            <input ng-model="sale_item.sale_item_price" value="{{ sale_item.sale_item_price }}" ng-change="syncWithItemWeight()" type="number" placeholder="Enter Price">
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$scope.sale_item = {};

$scope.syncWithItemWeight = function() {
  var itemPrice = $scope.sale_item.sale_item_price;
  $scope.sale_item.sale_item_weight = parseInt(itemPrice) * 2;
}

$scope.syncWithItemPrice = function() {
    var itemWeight = $scope.sale_item.sale_item_weight;
    $scope.sale_item.sale_item_price = parseInt(itemWeight) / 2;
}
```

Comment: thanks it worked.. can you please explain why direct scope variable weren't working.

Comment: @MubasharAbbas refer this link for better understanding about nested scopes http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/14/nested-scopes-in-angularjs.html